# Using "mod (%)" Operator For Getting Access to A Certain Element In the Vector

Tags: c++, vector, element

How can I use `mod(%)` operator to get access to a certain element in a vector in c++? The following line is already recognized erroneous by the compiler.

```
std::rotate((MyVector.begin()+i)%32,MyVector.begin()+j,MyVector.end());
```

Comment: May be you mean `std::rotate(MyVector.begin()+(i%32),MyVector.begin()+j,MyVector.end());`?

Comment: You probably want to use an iterator for the actual vector and not for the result. (check parentesis)

Comment: What is the behavior that you want to get? (MyVector.begin()+i)%32 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Right! MyVector.begin()+(i%32) must fulfill the requirement.